# Running two multi line queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following php script

```
    $maxmonth = date('m');
    $maxyear = date('Y');
    $sql = "SET @cmonth = 1;
            SET @cyear = 2015;
            SET @maxmonth = ".$maxmonth.";
            SET @maxyear = ".$maxyear.";

            CALL insertBills(@cyear,@cmonth,@maxyear,@maxmonth);";
    multiQuery($sql);

    $sql = "SET @cfmonth = 1;
            SET @cfyear = 2015;
            SET @maxfmonth = ".$maxmonth.";
            SET @maxfyear = ".$maxyear.";
            CALL insertFees(@cfyear,@cfmonth,@maxfyear,@maxfmonth);";
    multiQuery($sql);
```

The problem is the only one of them runs at a time. If I disable the first one, the second one works however both are not executed in one page refresh.

```
function multiQuery($sql) {
    global $dbi_connection;
    $dbi_result = mysqli_multi_query($dbi_connection,$sql);

    return $dbi_result;
}
```

Comment: Where is `multiQuery()` and what does it contain?

Comment: added the function multiQuery()

Comment: Thanks. Will you try adjusting the second `$sql` variable to `$sql2`, although I don't suppose that it needs to be however what we're looking at should work properly.

Comment: no deal... it seems to give the same result.
I tried using one multiQuery ($sql) at the end and concatenated the two $sql.

`$sql = "...";
$sql .= "...":

multiQuery($sql); //it works`

Comment: Your syntax isn't even right. You can't set to variables that aren't declared, and if you want to declare variables and set them prior to running a query with them, you should make a Stored Procedure and put the SQL code in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at how mysqli_multi_query works, you need to put your queries concatenated by a semicolon and then send that single query to the function.

Right now you are sending the two queries separately so it will only do one query at a time.

Comment: makes perfect sense and it works with your suggestion!